# Send notification mails via mailchimp api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to send an email notification via mailchimp.

I read the doc and I wrote some code so that I get the list by using `api.lists`:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'mailchimp'
@options = ["list_id" => "$list_id", "subject" => "test subject", "from_name" => "test name", "from_email" => "info@example.com"]
@content = ["html" => "<p> test content </p>"]
@type = 'regular'
@title = 'Test Newsletter Title'        
api = Mailchimp::API.new("key")
puts "Your lists:"
api.lists['data'].each do |list|
  puts "\t #{list['name']}"
end
```

**campaignCreate:**
I create a campaign like this:

```
api.campaignCreate(@type, @title, @content)
```

When I create a campaign by using the above then I get the following error: `wrong number of arguments (4 for 2)`

I want to send a notification email. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it, using this

```
 $LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
 $LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
 require 'mailchimp'
 api = Mailchimp::API.new("api-key")
 @content =  {"html"=>"<p> test content </p>","text"=> "test"}
 api.lists['data'].each do |list|
   @options =  {"list_id"=> list['id'], "subject"=>"test subject", "from_name"=>"test name", "from_email"=>"xyz@test.net", "template_id" => "xxxx"}
   campaign = api.campaignCreate({"type"=>"regular", "options" => @options, "content"=> @content})
   api.campaignSendNow({"cid" => campaign})
 end
```